# Lemma for Chinese Remainder Theorem

Tags: ring-theory, ideals, chinese-remainder-theorem

I want to prove the following *Lemma*:

Let $R$ be a commutative ring with $1\neq 0$ and $I,J_{1}, J_{2},..., J_{n}$ be the ideals of $R$ such that $I+J_{i}=R$ $\forall 1\leq i\leq n$. Then, $I$, $J_{1}J_{2}...J_{n}$ are co-maximal.

I have no idea how to approach it.

Also, I want to know what extra information do we get if $J_{1}, J_{2},..., J_{n}$ are pairwise co-maximal i.e. $J_{i}+J_{j}=R$ $\forall 1\leq i\neq j \leq n$.

Comment: It would be good to include the source of this problem, esp. if it is taken from an exercise in a textbook.  Knowing which textbook (if any) you are studying will help your Readers frame their Answers in suitable terms.

Comment: For you first problem, there are several approaches. Here is one. Two ideals are comaximal if and only if both are not contained in a prime (maximal) ideal. So, if $P$ is a prime ideal containing both $I$ and $\prod J_i$, then $P$ contains one of the $J_i$s, using the fact that $P$ is a prime. This is absurd, since then $P$ contains $I$ and one $J_i$.

Comment: @Mohan Thanks for your hint. But, I am puzzled by your statement "Two ideals are co-maximal if and only if both are not contained in a prime (maximal) ideal ". How do we prove this claim?

Comment: Two ideals $I,J$ are comaximal if and only if $I+J=R$. This is same as saying that both are not contained in a proper prime (maximal) ideal.

Comment: @Mohan Are we here using the following Lemma: If $R$ is a commutative Ring with $1\neq 0$, then $R$ has exactly one prime ideal.?

Comment: This is false. $R$ can have many prime ideals.

Comment: @Mohan It would be appreciable if you can give me some proof of the claim: "Two ideals are co-maximal if and only if both are not contained in a prime (maximal) ideal "

Comment: If $I,J$ are comaximal, by definition $I+J=R$, so no proper ideal can contain both $I$ and $J$. Conversely, if they are not comaximal, $I+J$ is a proper ideal and it is a standard fact that any proper ideal is contained in a maximal ideal by Zorn's lemma.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Hint**:

The hypothesis means that for each $i=1,\dots,n$, there exists a pair $(x_i, y_i),\;x_i\in I,y_i\in J_i$, such that $x_i+y_i=1$.

You can show by induction on $n$ that the product $(x_1+y_1)\dotsm(x_n+y_n)$, which is equal to $1$, can be expanded as $X+Y$, where $X\in I,\: Y\in J_1\dotsm J_n$.

Comment: Can you please also drop some comments for the second question?

Comment: Actually, w.r.t. the initial question, I don't see what it brings, except you may apply its result to the $J_i$: each  is comaximal with the product of the others.